# Which approch is better

Tags: algorithm, prime-factoring, greatest-common-divisor

Which approach gives better time complexity to find GCD(a,b) of a given number?

Prime factorization

(or)

the below approach

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    return (b==0)?a:gcd(b,a%b);
}
```

Comment: Define "better" first.

Comment: Define "better": Are you talking about code? Optimization? Readability/maintainability of the code?

Comment: @kviiri I am talking about time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the range of your input as well as your implementation of [Prime factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).
Since there's no efficient algorithm for large numbers for the latter, it seems like GCD can be implemented to provide more efficient results.

The main point is how modulo is calculated in your algorithm - assuming it's being implemented efficiently (without using division) this implementation of GCD (also called [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)) should be more efficient.